# Как сделать прием email на nginx

Tags: php, nginx, email

В nginx есть директива `mail{...}`

Как сделать так, чтобы приходящие письма на ***@example.com шли на обработку к php?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что Nginx проксирует все, в том числе, вероятно, и SMTP/IMAP/POP3 в асинхронном режиме с помощью `epoll` (под Линукс), то есть кусками. Скорее всего, придется писать модуль на C, который собирает все письмо и отправляет на обработку модулю PHP. Это сложно. Тем более, документация по C API у них никакая и нигде. Хуже чем у PHP даже.